# A digitizer for technical visio style drawings?

Tags: microsoft-visio

I am looking for advice and experience for using a digitizer for doing technical drawings. I do a lot of those when I do IT-integrations architechture and integrations dataflow drawings.

And I am tired of moving Visio boxes around and spending forever drawing little arrows.

I was thinking about getting a digitizer and using that to get started. But have no experience about what king of integration there is to non-artistic drawing apps. Anybody have any experience along these lines?

Comment: What's your definition of a "digitizer" exactly?  Like a [CAD Digitizer](http://www.gtcocalcomp.com/photos/PHcadprotablet500.jpg)?

Comment: I'm thinking WACOM tablet, like one of these http://www.wacom.com/us/en/creative/intuos-s

Comment: why not use a windows tablet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a Wacom tablet instead of a mouse in general when i use my PC. I far prefer using the pen when drawing in Visio.

Having said that, Visio doesn't really take advantage of any of the tablet's artistic features: pressure sensitivity, eraser, etc.

If you are considering any using a tablet then get a basic model to start wit. Monoprice makes a very inexpensive one for example (here's a review: http://frenden.com/post/31659364200/the-little-monoprice-graphics-tablet-that-could ).

Comment: Thanks. I just ordered a basic WACOM to test it out, but thanks for the visio heads up.